# How to add ellipsis in enumeration in markdown?

Tags: support, markdown

I would like to render a list in markdown with numbers 1, 2, 3, ..., 10

My first attempt

```
1. one
2. two
3. three  
...
10. ten
```

produces

1. one
2. two
3. three
   ...
4. ten

the number that should be 10 is not 10, it is 4.

My other attempt

```
 1. one
 2. two
 3. three

...

10. ten
```

1. one
2. two
3. three

...

10. ten

has the ellipsis in an ugly position that aligns less well with the list than in my first attempt.

Is there a way to skip items with ellipsis in a numbered list in this site's markdown?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

A hack, presumably, but I found that in a HTML style ordered  list `<ol>...</ol>`, just typing without making a list item `<li>` gives the same indent, but with no number or bullet. Hence

```
 1. one
 2. two
 3. three  
<ol>
...
</ol>

 10. ten
```

gives

1. one
2. two
3. three

  ...

10. ten

Answer (score -6):

`a \cdots b` looks like $a \cdots b$.